# My supervisor is forcing me to change my PhD thesis to masters after 4 years of my PhD and passing all of exams, is that possible?

Tags: phd, thesis, masters, australia

I am student in one of Australia Universities, my PhD supervisor is forcing to change my thesis from PhD to masters and this after 4 years of my candidature after passing all of my exams of conformation, mid candidature and final review, is it possible that he recommended that at thesis submission point? or it is examiners decision and does he have an authority to force my examiners to just give me master? and according to what circumstances they may recommended masters? noting that my thesis contain chapter of review, and 3 expiremental chapters. Thanks

Comment: This is a local question to be worked out with the university.

Comment: I would interpret this as your supervisor is considering you as having failed the PhD, which indeed they may have the power to do though you may have avenues to appeal or have an alternate sponsor. Like Buffy writes, this is going to depend on your university's policies.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  It does not matter how many internal reviews you passed.     What is important is the recommendation of external examiners.  If your supervisor(s) deemed that you have not carried out enough work, and does not meet the examination criteria, then he/she may advise you to submit as a Master.  You can still go ahead and submit it as a PhD but you may fail.